# Line Break In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a line break in xamarin. I want the line break between the description and the new text which starts at "Date created:"

[image: Image of what it currently looks like]

Below is what the current code looks like;
This is the code in xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Expenses}" HasUnevenRows="True"
          SeparatorColor="Gray" ItemSelected="OnExpenseSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ExpenseImage}"
                       Text="{Binding FullName}"
                       Detail="{Binding MoreDetail}"
                       DetailColor="Black"
                       TextColor="Blue">
                <ImageCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete Expense"
                              IsDestructive="true"
                              Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=ViewModel.DeleteExpenseCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                              />


                </ImageCell.ContextActions>
            </ImageCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And this is the code I currently have in c#

```
public string MoreDetail
{
   get { return string.Format("{0}" + "\r\n" + "Date Created: {1}", Summary, TodaysDate); }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.NewLine` instead of "\r\n" as not all platforms using "\r" for line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `Detail`  propery does not support multiple lines of text of `ImageCell` (include `TextCell`).

So you could use a grid to achieve the effect:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ExpenseImage}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" TextColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding MoreDetail}" TextColor="Black"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
              </ViewCell.View>
              <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                   <MenuItem Text="Delete Expense"
                          IsDestructive="true"
                          Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=ViewModel.DeleteExpenseCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                          />
              </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```